# How to input emails into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, imap

So i am trying to store emails from gmail, i have already connected everything and i manage to store all the email content into database but now i have problem that every time that i refresh page the same emails are being stored in database.

```
$bodyText = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.2);

if(!strlen($bodyText)>0){
    $bodyText = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1);
}
$subject = imap_headerinfo($inbox,$email_number);
$subject = $subject->subject;
$stripped = str_replace('*', '<br>', $bodyText);

$sql = "SELECT id, subject, body FROM emails";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $email_subject = $row['subject'];
    if ($subject == $email_subject) {
        echo "Email already in database";
    }else{
         $sql = "INSERT INTO emails (subject, body)
        VALUES ('".$subject."', '".$stripped."')";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
     }
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

So i tried using this

```
if ($subject == $email_subject) {
        echo "Email already in database";
    }else{
         $sql = "INSERT INTO emails (subject, body)
        VALUES ('".$subject."', '".$stripped."')";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
     }
```

Which is suposed to check if in the database there is emails with the same subject, and if there is it will display "Email already in database" and if there isn't its suposed to display "New record created successfully"

Put something is wrong and i keep getting same emails in the database, so each time that i reffresh whole inbox of my email goes into database

Comment: **Warning:** You might be open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: See [imap_uid](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-uid.php)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, i am just trying something on my localhost, once i manage do add all the functions that i require i update the code, i will read about MySqli

Comment: @Dharman there are more ways to corrupt data to add to your comment, the much feared NULL byte see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9KAowbtEYo9nFEbDoubFiM/0) notice i inserted a duplicated email while the email column has a UNIQUE key.. use `str_replace("\0", '', $string)` in PHP to filter that out.. In MySQL 8.0 this is fixed see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9KAowbtEYo9nFEbDoubFiM/0)

Comment: Also the topicstarters method is prone to race conditions, without a unique key.

Comment: @JovanDjordjevic If I had a dollar for every time someone used "temporary" code in production, I'd be a wealthy man. Making it work and *then* adding security later is an invitation to disaster. Start using prepared statements now and avoid the headache later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should always use prepared statements of [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL Injections.

Also looks like you are looping your entries in the database and checking your current email against every entry.
What you should do is to use SELECT query with subject of current email as a WHERE parameter to check if this subject is already in the database.

Alternatively use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` when inserting new record.

Comment: You can use prepared statements with either PDO or MySQLi. It is prepared statements that prevent SQL injections.

Comment: Thanks this answer helped me